# OneToMany mapping using separate table, Hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, kotlin

I use this tables:

```
-- Creation employee table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee
(
    employee_id          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);

-- Creation advance_report table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS advance_report
(
    advance_report_id    SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);

-- Creation guests table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS guests
(
    advance_report_id  INT REFERENCES advance_report (advance_report_id),
    employeeId    INT REFERENCES employee (employee_id)
);
```

And this models for mapping

```
@Entity
@Table(appliesTo = "advance_report")
open class AdvanceReport(
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "advance_report_id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    open var id: Long? = null,
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    @JoinTable(
        name = "guests",
        joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "advance_report_id")],
        inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")]
    )
    val guests: Set<Employee>? = null,
    
)

@Entity
@Table(appliesTo = "employee")
open class Employee(
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "employee_id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    open var id: Long? = null,
    
)
```

But when I try to map advance_report_id and employee_id using 'guests' table, I get this error:

> Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: ru.vtb.test.pr.models.new.AdvanceReport.guests, could not initialize proxy - no Session; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: ru.vtb.test.pr.models.new.AdvanceReport.guests, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: ru.vtb.test.pr.models.new.AdvanceReport["guests"])]

Comment: Have you tried to use [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=failed+to+lazily+initialize+a+collection+of+role+no+session)?

Comment: Hi. I understood from your comment in my deleted answer that the issue is resolved. Maybe just delete the question in order to avoid people spending time on this? BR